# automorphic forms associated with symmetries of vertices of uniform honeycombs in hyperbolic space

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms, hyperbolic-geometry, lattices, automorphic-forms

Is there a catalogue of automorphic forms (modular/Maass/Siegel/Hilbert...) which lists them in terms of [Poincaré series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_series_(modular_form)) associated with the symmetries of [the vertices of uniform honeycombs in hyperbolic space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_honeycombs_in_hyperbolic_space)?